# Subtracting each element from another element in a column In Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to subtract each element from other element in a vector in matlab. I know that diff(X) gives the difference of elements. Suppose

```
x = {1
     3 
     3 
     6 
     8
     10 
     15 
     23}

DiffX = diff (x);
```

will result in

```
DiffX = {2
         0
         3 
         2 
         2 
         5 
         8}
```

However what I am looking for is the difference of each element from each element something like that

```
DiffX = {0
         2
         2
         5
         7
         9
         14
         22
         -2
         0 
         0
         3
         5
         7
         12
         20
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         0}
```

Which comes from

```
DiffX = {x(1) - x(1), x(2) - x(1), x(3) - (1), x(4) - x(1), ... , x(8) - x(1), x(1) - x(2), x(2) - x(2), x(3) - x(2), ......., x(8) - x(8)}
```

What I dont know is how to put that in a loop to get the answer. Help is much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Why is `x` a cell array? Any reason it can't be `x=[1 3 3 6 8 10 15 23]`?

Comment: Just noticed that I had put x as a cell which was a mistake. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `bsxfun(@plus, x,-x')`. This appies the element-by-element binary operation `+` to the arrays x and -x' (negative x transposed).

---

As (was) indicated in the comments, the same can be achieved by `bsxfun(@minus, x, x')`.

---

If the result needs to be a vector, you should change it to `reshape(bsxfun(@minus, x', x),[],1)`. See also the comment of Robert P below.

By the way, the syntax in your question is a bit confusing. As was said before, `{` and `}` implies that the result is a cell array, while applying `diff` indicates a normal array. Also, the notation for the assigning of values to `x` suggests a normal vector result, but the absence of `;` implies that the result will be a row-vector. Anyway, play around with transpose symbols, and the desired result should emerge.

Comment: Remember that `x` is a cell array. That doesn't work on cell arrays.

Comment: Well, executing the `diff` does not work on cells as well. Making it work for cells can be done by `cell2mat(x)`.

Comment: +1, but I think it should be `bsxfun(@plus, -x, x')` to get the signs correct. @Matlaber: if you want it to be a single column vector, you can do: `reshape(bsxfun(@plus, -x, x'),[],1)`, or `res = res(:)` where `res` is the result of the `bsxfun`.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering, maybe you can achieve something similar with normal vector difference operations?

Starting from something like this:

```
x = [1 3 3 6 8 10 15 23]

X = repmat(x,size(x,2),1)
```

doing the difference of `X` and its transpose should get you differences between all combinations of elements in `x`:

```
X - X'
```

At this point you should select appropriately the elements that you are interested in (upper triangular matrix?) and flatten into a vector.

Comment: `bsxfun` is normally more efficient than using repmat e.g. http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/

Answer (score 0):

`bsxfun` is the best way to go but this is how you do it using loops (don't do it this way, this is just to illustrate the concept of loops):

I suggest that you store the result in a 2D matrix, in which case the loop solution is simple:

```
x = {1 3 3 6 8 10 15 23}

D = zeros(numel(x));  %// This preallocation step is essential for efficiency in Matlab
for A = 1:numel(x)
    for B = 1:numel(x)
        D(A,B) = x{A} - x{B};
    end
end
```